# C++: How do I subtract two integers from different classes?

Tags: c++

**Before I say anything, I want to clarify I am a beginner programmer and have only spent about 2 months on C++.**

I've had this problem for a while now and I can't seem to find the answer!

**To make it clear, I am not trying to optimize this "game". I am simply trying to practice my classes.**

Here is the example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Health = Health - dmgNinja;
    cout << Health << endl;    
}
```

In a separate class header:

```
class Enemy {
public:
    void dmgNinja();
};
```

In a separate class cpp:

```
int dmgNinja = 42;

namespace std {

void Enemy::dmgNinja() {
    cout << dmgNinja << endl;
}

}
```

In a separate class header:

```
class Bandit {
public:
    void Health();
};
```

In a separate class cpp:

```
int Health = 100;

namespace std {

void Bandit::Health() {
    cout << Health << endl;
}

}
```

In short, I want to know how to subtract two variables from different classes and then print it out in the main file, making sure whatever variable was changed stays changed.

Comment: Please __don't__ use the namespace `std` for your own stuff. Thats the standard-libraries namespace!

Comment: Don't enclose your code in `namespace std{}` use `std::cout` and `std::endl` instead. In fact don't use `std::endl` use `'\n'`. `;)`

Comment: That will not compile because *Health* is not defined in your main. Also you should most certainly not put your stuff into namespace std.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
class Taco
{
 public:
   int sauce;
};
class Burrito
{
  public:
    int cheese;
};

int main(void)
{
  Burrito b;
  Taco    t;
  b.cheese = 5;
  t.sauce  = 3;
  int difference = 0;
  // Here's the subtraction
  difference = b.cheese - t.sauce;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This is probably the simplest way to do it. @Pablo the problem your probably having is not making your variables part of the class.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know It was probably a stupid question but I couldn't find the answer. One more question. I get how to subtract the classes now. So If i wanted to change b.cheese to 2. Then would i do b.cheese = b.cheese - t.sauce?

Comment: If you want to change `b.cheese` to 2, you would do `b.cheese = 2;`.  Treat them as you would a variable not in a structure.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please click on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct problem, you need to declare `Health` as an `extern` in either a header or in your main.cpp file.

You have numerous other problems though, including use of globals which is to be highly discouraged.  Take that as part of the learning process and being a beginner.

BTW, your question is highly misleading because what you're actually trying to do is simply subtract one integer from another and assign the result back into one of the operands.  At no point are your classes being used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions there.

About substracting two attributes from different classes, it mostly depends on where you intend to perform the substraction.

The rule is that both attributes must be visible from there.
So it might be, for instance, public attributes (visible everywhere), or private attributes with an accessor method, or attributes of a friend class.

*All this fuss about privacy might seem like a hassle at first, but that's what makes big amounts code (something like 10.000 lines or more) manageable. If you restrict access to a given value, only a small bit of code will be likely to modify it, and finding the cause of a bug will be easier than if you had to check the whole project for a wrong line of code.

Apart from that, declaring a variable public or private has no effect on the code that is actually generated by the compiler. It's purely a matter of keeping things in check.

That's why beginers are constantly reminded that global variables are the wrong easy way out. Deciding where to put your data and which parts of your program will be authorized to read or write it is a bit of extra work. In small educational examples it might not seem to serve any purpose.

But once you'll have written your own few hundred lines of code and sweated through a few debugging sessions, you'll soon realize how useful it is. For now let's say you'll need a small leap of faith :).*

Now about the "whatever variable (that) was changed stays changed", it's basically a matter of lifespan of your variables.
Hopefully you'll have had lectures about that. Global variables, local variables, dynamic variables. The sanct trinity of lifespan.

In your case, I don't quite see what your problem is. If your goal is indeed to print a difference, you don't even need a variable to store it.

```
void print_diff(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;

    printf ("%d - %d = %d\n", a, b, a-b);
}
```

Here there are only two values stored, in variables `a` and `b`.
The difference `a-b` exists inside the computer only for the time needed to fetch the values, substract them and let `printf` display the result.
You might store this difference in some local, global or dynamic variable, even write it to disk to make it last as long as your hard drive doesn't fail, but what would be the point?